# rearranging 2*2 pixel images, each given by 1 by 4 numpy vectors, into a single 8 by 8 matrix without using a for loop

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, reshape, imshow

in an assignment for a uni class i am given multiple images in vectors, and i need to display multiple of them by rearranging them into a single matrix.

assume the given vectors:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4],[5, 6, 7, 8],[9, 10, 11, 12],[13,14,15,16]]
```

where each pair of 4 values within a vector describes a 2x2 pixel image
my task is to rearrange this into a 4x4 matrix:

```
[[1,2,5,6],[3,4,7,8],[8,9,12,13],[10,11,15,16]]
```

without using a single for loop. i have tried multiple variants of reshapes, but have no idea how to actually solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's use `reshape`, and `swapaxes`:

```
arrs = [[1, 2, 3, 4],[5, 6, 7, 8],[9, 10, 11, 12],[13,14,15,16]]

np.array(arrs).reshape(2,2,2,2).swapaxes(1,2).reshape(4,4)
```

Output:

```
array([[ 1,  2,  5,  6],
       [ 3,  4,  7,  8],
       [ 9, 10, 13, 14],
       [11, 12, 15, 16]])
```